# Joining new SE site with association bonus: +98 rep visual glitch

Tags: bug, reputation, association-bonus, association

I just joined Code Review SE and was surprised by this visual glitch:
[image]

It says "+98" on the top right corner, but the popup clearly states "+100". I can think of 2 possibilities:

1. I started with 2 rep when I joined.
2. I got downvoted right before I joined Code Review.

The second possibility seems more likely, but I'm not sure that I got downvoted just a minute ago.